# Is it possible to use MongoDB with flash/flex?

Tags: mongodb, flash, flex4, nosql

Is it possible to connect MongoDB with Flash/Flex and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is straight AS3 bindings for mongo. [This post](http://www.justria.com/2009/12/21/get-schema-free-within-minutes/) explains how to use mongo in flex

from the above link

> Yet, MongoDB doesn’t come with an AS3
>   binding. To get access to MongoDB from
>   within your Flex/Air app, various ways
>   exist. One might use MongoDB’s
>   PHP-driver, add some AMFPHP magic and
>   finally expose your MongoDB’s API to
>   flex

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [MongoAS3](http://www.mongoas3.com/) by @s9tpepper :

> An ActionScript 3 driver for mongodb that works without the use of a server side language such as PHP, Java, .Net, etc. The driver is written in pure AS3 so it is usable in both pure AS3/Flash projects as well as Flex projects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MongoDB's REST interface (json) and on the flex side use as3 corelib. This way you wouldn't need Java or PHP in between.

[Tutorial : Using JSON with Flex 2 and ActionScript 3](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2006/03/28/tutorial-using-json-with-flex-2-and-actionscript-3/)
[Mongo Extended JSON](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It has been implemented at [MTV](http://www.10gen.com/presentation/mongonyc-2011/how-mtv-networks-leverages-mongodb-for-cms).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new powerful driver 
for MongoDB for FLEX. You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/jmcnet-full-mongo-flex-driver/)
The community seems to be active and features sounds great :

Main features are :

- connection pooling,
- Safe mode enabling,
- Direct CRUD object manipulation,
- Full Aggregation support (group, MapReduce, ...),
- BSON encoder and decoder,
- ObjectID helper.